# How do I calculate the Hausdorff $2$-measure of a square directly?

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

It is well-known that the Hausdorff $n$-measure (with suitable normalization) agrees with the Lebesgue measure on Euclidean $n$-space. Thus, it's clear that the $H^2$ measure of the unit square is $1$.

However, I cannot find or create a direct proof of this fact from the definition of Hausdorff measure as the limit of the Hausdorff content:

$$ H^{d}_{\delta} (S) := \inf \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\omega_d}{2^d}(\operatorname{diam} U_i )^d : \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_i \supseteq S, \operatorname{diam} U_i < \delta \right\}.$$

I have tried covering with squares and with circles so far, but so far the lowest Hausdorff content I can find is $\pi/2$, which is the Hausdorff content of a covering made of $2^n$ smaller squares.

To clarify the question: find a sequence of covers $\{U_i\}$ of $S$ with so that the diameter of the sets in each cover approaches zero and the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\omega_d}{2^d}(\operatorname{diam} U_i )^d$ approaches 1.

Note: $\omega_d$ is the volume of the $d$-dimensional unit ball. A source proving agreement of this normalization with Lebesgue measure can be found in these lecture notes from CUHK professor Kai-Seng Chou: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1415/math5011/MATH5011_Chapter_3.2014.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj975GE_7rxAhWMMd8KHSETDycQFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2ak7RZJQW-6f6Gth2OTBoc. See pages 14 and 18.

Comment: Are you sure the normalization is correct? I think there's a factor of $2^{-d}$ missing?

Comment: Even if so, that wouldn't get rid of the extra factor of $\pi$? But my normalization constant $\omega_d$ is the volume of the $d$ dimensional unit ball.

Comment: You are right about the normalization constant, formula edited!

Comment: I've seen the proof in my lesson. It's not easy to show that $\mathcal H^n=\mathcal L^n$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: It follows from the fact that all Haar measures on a locally compact space are equivalent up to a constant factor. This isn't easy to show but it is well-known.

Comment: I'm confused. You start out by saying that Hausdorff measure **with suitable normalization** agrees with Lebesgue measure. Are you asking whether that particular formula you give for Hausdorff measure is **suitably normalized**?

Comment: Also, what is $S$?

Comment: S is the unit square (or any set you're measuring the Hausdorff content of). We know that $H(S)=1$ for the unit square $S$ when we use the normalization given in this definition. Some authors use a different normalization by setting $\omega_d=1$, but the constant we've chosen makes it agree with the Lebesgue measure. The question is to prove that fact directly from the definition (i.e. without resorting to more abstract arguments like the uniqueness of Haar measures)

Comment: So, just to make sure that I understand clearly, you already know (from some source?) that with the particular normalization in your post the equation $H(S)=1$ is true? But if that's so then it would help to clarify your post if you could give the source.

Comment: I forget the original source from which I learned this, since this is common knowledge in measure theory, but I've added a source that proves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We work with the open unit square $(0,1)^2$ for ease.

You basically have to use circles as the $U_i$'s, since they are the only shape with $\frac{\pi}{4}\text{diam}(U)^2 = \text{Area}(U)$.

First, take $n \in \mathbb{N}$ large and even so that $\frac{2}{n} < \delta$. Then make a grid of $\frac{n^2}{4}$ circles each of diameter $\frac{2}{n}$ with centers at $(\frac{2j+1}{n},\frac{2k+1}{n})$ for $0 \le j,k \le \frac{n}{2}-1$. Let $\mathcal{U}^{(1)}$ be the collection of these circles.

Perform the following algorithm. For each $t \ge 1$, let $C_1^{(t)},\dots,C_{m_t}^{(t)}$ be the connected components of $[0,1]^2\setminus \mathcal{U}^{(t)}$. For each $1 \le j \le m_t$, choose the largest circle $D_j^{(t)}$ that can fit completely inside $C_j^{(t)}$. Let $\mathcal{U}^{(t+1)} = \mathcal{U}^{(t)}\cup\bigcup_{i=1}^{m_t} D_j^{(t)}$.

Let $\mathcal{U} = \cup_{t \ge 1} \mathcal{U}^{(t)}$. Now, $\mathcal{U}$ is countable, so we may write it as $\mathcal{U} = \{U_1,U_2,\dots\}$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\mathcal{U}^{(\epsilon)} = \{U_1^{(\epsilon)},U_2^{(\epsilon)},\dots\}$, where $U_j^{(\epsilon)}$ is the same circle as $U_j$ except with $(1+\epsilon)$ times the radius. Then $\cup_{j \ge 1} U_j^{(\epsilon)}$ covers $(0,1)^2$.

So, $1 \ge \sum_{j \ge 1} \text{Area}(U_j^{(\epsilon)}) = (1+\epsilon)^2\sum_{j \ge 1} \text{Area}(U_j)$. So, $\sum_{i \ge 1} \frac{\pi}{4}\text{diam}(U_i^{(\epsilon)})^2 = \sum_{i \ge 1} \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{4}{\pi}\text{Area}(U_i^{(\epsilon)}) \le \frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)^2}$.

As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the proof is complete.

Comment: Could you provide further justification for why every point is covered by the algorithm at some stage?

Comment: @MathTrain See the updated answer.

Comment: I see that this probably solves the problem, but can you explicitly explain why we know the $\epsilon$-expanded set covers the square?

Comment: Bumping my prior comment, could you explain how this fixes the problem?